# JanusGraph Not enough replicas available for query at consistency QUORUM

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph, scylla

We have 7 nodes storage cluster with RF=4 and CL=ONE. Janus Graph has below settings in properties file-

`storage.cql.replication-factor=4
storage.cql.read-consistency-level=ONE
storage.cql.write-consistency-level=ONE
log.tx.key-consistent=true`

When we stopped 2 nodes (out of 7) , Janus Graph failing with below errors:

`gremlin-server.log:Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.UnavailableException: Not enough replicas available for query at consistency QUORUM (3 required but only 2 alive)`

I tried `log.tx.key-consistent=true` , but its not working.

Can you please assist here?

Answer (score 2):

Obliviously there is a quorum operation going on. Seems like the configuration of cl=1 wasn't enough

Comment: As per these link's it's Janus Graph bug / issue - https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/913  
  and https://issue.life/questions/48593532

Comment: We have CL=1 at ScyllaDB cluster level (by default). Is there any way to check CL at transaction level in ScyllaDB? and can it be restrict to have CL=1?